# How to extract the value that is in JSON format in MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table `WEBSITE_IMAGES` in which one of the field name called `Value` has data in JSON format.

`Value` field looks like below: 
I am wondering how I can extract `product_name` and `image_name` only. (eg: `14669 golden.png`, `14754 tealglass.png`)

```
{"1235":"custom_images","options":{"1235":{"product_image":"image","color":"","image":"{\"14669\":\"\/s\/i\/golden.png\",\"14754\":\"\/s\/m\/tealglass.png\"
```

Comment: seems the json format is wrong in the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is the set your directory addresses in the programming settings side.
In case of file trouble or migration, you will have problem with your files and data.  Keep your data simple.   Let your program do the file locations later.
With that, you will have less trouble with slashes and conversion.